# "Method too complex" exception is thrown

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am creating android apps using Xamarin C# and SQLITE as database.

I have created C# class say 'DBCreate.cs' containing around 6000 insert statements and that class takes SQLITECONNECTION object as parameter. In my main database class I am creating SQLITECONNECTION object and then I am passing same object to DBExtened.cs. I am getting error that `method is too complex`:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you click on the `Show Details` button and add that to the question?

Comment: Do you really need to seed that much data from code?  Have you considered including a pre-seeded copy of the db with your app instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a limitation on the byte-code. The solution is simple: make the method "less complex" or "much smaller".

That is, split all the code up between *multiple* methods or, better, extract the *data* from the *method/usage sites*.

---

I recommend extracting the data such that there are not 6k insert statements! While I would likely use an *external* data-source (such as a file), using arrays and loops to populate the data would avoid this error and possibly create for more space-efficient compiled code.

Comment: Do you recommend me to use partial class in this case, so that i will put 3k insert statement in one rest 3k in another partial class?

Comment: @OvaisKhan No. If you do simply split the insert calls between methods, keep them in one non-partial class (the partial class will compile to the same bytecode anyway). And if they can't be split in any logical way (i.e. they all insert random data into the same table), name the methods `InsertRecords1, InsertRecords2, ..` or something else sequential. (Then `InsertRecords` calls each of the `InsertRecords{N}` methods in turn.)